# Cannot start NFS: Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no support in current kernel

Tags: debian, nfs

I installed NFS on a new Debian7 install. I did:

```
apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```

add folder to share to `/etc/exports`: `/home/share *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)`

```
service nfs-kernel-server start
```

But after this I get this error:

```
[warn] Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no support in current kernel. ... (warning).
```

I googled for this, but didn't find the solution yet. Some say the check `/proc/config.gz`, but I haven't this file in `/proc`

Comment: Please provide the output of `uname -a`.

Comment: uname -a gives: Linux h2523591.stratoserver.net 3.2.41-042stab111.12 #1 SMP Thu Sep 17 11:38:20 MSK 2015 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the NFS module is not loaded. Try `modprobe nfs` and restart the nfs service.

Comment: Tried modprobe nfs, but get this error: libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.2.41-042stab111.12/modules.dep.bin'

Comment: Your kernel modules directory seems to have some problem. Try `depmod -a`, then retry with `modprobe nfs`

Comment: depmod -a gives: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.2.41-042stab111.12: No such file or directory
FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory

Comment: You had serious problems with your installed kernel. Try to uninstall and reinstall it via `apt-get`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of shodanshok and the comments:

- It seems your hosting provider removed the `nfs` modules in the version you've installed. Maybe they want to prevent that users exporting "by accident" their `/` or `/home` to the public internet.
- Not sure if this is a dedicated, virtualized or containerized server and if you're able to switch to / install a different kernel: If so, install a vanilla `Debian` [kernel](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/linux-image-amd64), otherwise, speak to the support of your hoster.

Comment: it is a vps. Maybe better try with samba, I thought nfs was simple, but for me costs me too much time and fustration. Thanks for help!